# cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found

Tags: go, gcc, mingw, tdm-gcc

I am using Windows 10.
I am trying to run a simple Go program but I am getting an error

```
# github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka
cgo: C compiler "gcc" not found: exec: "gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

I know it's recommended to install MinGW or TDM-GCC,but unfortunately I can't install these programs due to user restrictions. Is there another way to solve it? Perhaps gcc may come as part of some other Windows programs?

Comment: confluent-kafka-go links in a C library and requires a C compiler. You might want to re-ask without the Go tag and with something like "Is there a C compiler or gcc alternative I can install on windows" and then include as much as you can about the restrictions on programs you can install.

Answer (score 0):

Get a standalone MinGW-w64 build from https://winlibs.com/

No install privileges needed, just unzip the download.